# MySQL JSON_SEARCH and JSON_REPLACE don't escape quotes

Tags: java, mysql, json, escaping

I have a JSON column in a MySQL DB. I'm trying to replace a JSON object with another using

```
UPDATE table SET ColName = JSON_REPLACE(ColName, '{"sample": "sample"}');
```

It seems after executing this statement, MySQL is inserting \" escaped quotes around my JSON properties like so:

> {\"sample\": \"sample\"}

This is causing my JSON_SEARCH query to fail in finding "sample" due to the escaped quotes. Is there a way I can use JSON_REPLACE without having it add escapes to the double quotes?

I tried wrapping JSON_UNQUOTE around JSON_REPLACE in my update statement, this did don't resolve the issue.

Comment: I guess you need to pass a JSON object, and not a varchar: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object

Comment: Try: `... CAST('{"sample": "sample"}' AS JSON) ...`. See [12.10 Cast Functions and Operators::CAST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Answer (score 2):

wchiquito's answer worked

"Try `... CAST('{"sample": "sample"}' AS JSON) ...`"

wchiquito, I can change the accepted answer to your comment if you post an answer.